# List not shown in harmon.ie due to view threshold limit

Tags: harmon.ie

I get the error "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator" in harmon.ie for a list with document sets. I can search for a specific document set and that set is visible in harmon.ie.
The list contains 12000+ items and the view is working fine in the library. If I create a view with only 5 document sets it still cannot be shown in harmon.ie.

How do I get the list to be visible in harmon.ie?

Comment: The problem is in Outlook

Comment: Make sure to download our latest 6.4 version from our web site. Unset option "Load items by Date modified (start with most recent)" and make sure to define a default view selecting less items than the List view threshold. The fields selected in the view must also indexed. ----Jean

Comment: After enforcing these changes, the list can be shown and documents can be searched with success. However if the user try to sort a column and then select a folder, they get the same error. If they do not sort any columns they can open the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to download our latest 6.4 version from our web site. Unset option "Load items by Date modified (start with most recent)" and make sure to define a default view selecting less items than the List view threshold. The fields selected in the view must also indexed.

----Jean

Comment: The unset of option "Load items by Date" worked.
But how do I check which version I have?

Comment: Look at "About" dialog in harmon.ie sidebar